# Passport js Error 401: invalid_client The OAuth client was not found

Tags: node.js, express, oauth

I am using Passport js in Express for authenticating user with Google. I am using `Passport` for oauth servicing and `passport-google-oauth20` for GoogleStrategy and i am using `Express` for server side. So following is my code ....

```
const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport')
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy
const key = require('./config/key')
const app = express()

  passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: key.googleClientSecret,
    clientSecret: key.googleClientSecret,
    callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
  },(accessToken)=>{
     console.log(accessToken)
  })
)

app.get('/auth/google',passport.authenticate('google', {
   scope: ['profile','email']
}))

app.get('/auth/google/callback',passport.authenticate('google'))

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT)
```

and following is my package.json script

```
"scripts": {
"start": "node index.js",
"dev": "nodemon index.js"
}
```

i am using `nodemon` for auto running server. And i have also create project in `google.developers.console` for client_id and client_secret. But when i run the server it just redirect me to the following url and show the following error.

url: `https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/error?authError=Cg5pbnZhbGlkX2NsaWVudBIfVGhlIE9BdXRoIGNsaWVudCB3YXMgbm90IGZvdW5kLiCRAw%3D%3D&client_id=z02cLybsfbgFxwA3d60Iuc5u`

error:
[image]

Comment: This is a typo You set the ClientSecret as the clientID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    clientID: key.googleClientSecret,
    clientSecret: key.googleClientSecret,
```

You set the `googleClientSecret` as the clientID. That doesn't seem right :)

Comment: Thank you so much. It was just that spelling mistake. Now everything is working now i just replace 

    clientID: key.googleClientID,
    clientSecret: key.googleClientSecret,